# Recognize template filename extension?

Tags: major-mode, files

I use a template engine for a lot of files in my project.  The specific one is irrelevant -- let's say all my template files end with `.template`.

Now, I've got many different kinds of templated files, like `foo.txt.template`, `bar.html.template`, `baz.py.template`, and `qux.json.template`.

By default, Emacs doesn't know about my template engine, so they all open in fundamental-mode.  I could manually add each templated filetype to my .emacs file (`.txt.template`, `.html.template`, etc), but that's tedious, and I'll have to update it whenever anybody finds a new filetype that's useful to template.

Is there an easy way to tell Emacs' major-mode-selection functionality that `.template` is special, and that any file that looks like `foo.ext.template` should be opened as if it were called `foo.ext`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto-mode-alist` is the variable that determines what major mode a file is opened in. Part of its documentation is:

```
Alist of filename patterns vs corresponding major mode functions.
Each element looks like (REGEXP . FUNCTION) or (REGEXP FUNCTION NON-NIL).

...

If the element has the form (REGEXP FUNCTION NON-NIL), then after
calling FUNCTION (if it’s not nil), we delete the suffix that matched
REGEXP and search the list again for another match.
```

So this will make Emacs open, for example, foo.html.template in html-mode:

```
(push '("\\.template\\'" nil t) auto-mode-alist)
```

Comment: this is much more elegant than my solution.  I even read that part of the documentation without realizing this is what it could be used for.

Answer (score 1):

The normal procedure for specifying file extensions works here,

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ext.template" . ext-mode))
```

Just add a line like this for each mode you're interested in.  To speed things up you can use `C-h v` to find the current value of `auto-mode-alist` and copy the entries for extensions you want.

Comment: The point of the question (paragraph 3) is that I don't know a priori what modes I'm interested in.